# std::strstreambuf::sbumpc(); always give -1

Tags: c++

Can any body explain why my following code always give -1 ? Thanks

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <strstream>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        {
                char a[20] = {"abcde"};
                std::strstreambuf sb0(a, 10, a);
                std::cout<<sb0.sbumpc()<<std::endl;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is used as an output buffer. For example, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstreambuf/strstreambuf) gives us this example:

```
char buf[10];
std::strstreambuf user(buf, 10, buf); // user-provided output buffer
std::ostrstream user_s(buf, 10); // equivalent stream
user_s << 1.23 << std::ends;
std::cout << buf << '\n';
```

Similarly, without using `ostrstream`, you can see the following example:

```
char a[20];
std::strstreambuf sb0(a, 10, a);
sb0.sputc('a');
a[1] = '\0';
std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
```

outputs `a`.